# Every time I plug my sound cable off or in, my external hdd becomes inaccessible. What to do?

Tags: hard-drive

I've got TV plugged into my computer through HDMI and speakers via standard sound cable. Every time I want sound to go into TV, I just plug my sound cable off (socket is on the top face of my tower, so it's not inconvenient) and Windows automatically channels sound into HDMI. And every time my external HDD, which is ADATA NH92, goes dark - it's there in the list of all disks, but I can't access anything on it. If I try Windows just goes into an infinite loop of trying to access it. Only solution is turning HDD off and in (btw, it's connected via mini USB-to-dual standard USB connector).

The same thing happens if I plug sound cable in.

What's going on ?

Comment: That's just wierd. Does it happen with any set of ports?

Comment: Look for something like power surge caused by sound cable. That's my best guess.

Comment: So I've experimented with other stuff connected to the computer. If I plug off and in HDMI cable, same thing happens - HDD becomes inaccessible and needs plugging off and in. On the other hand, keyboard, mouse, and iPod all plugged through USB, when plugged off and in, don't have that influence on my hdd.